# MonoGame cannot be referenced after install on Linux

Tags: linux, mono, monogame, gac

I've downloaded latest MonoGame on Linux and did `sudo sh monogame-sdk.run`

It installed some assemblies at `/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/MonoGame/v3.0`, but they're absent from GAC: `gacutil -l` doesn't list MonoGame and it only lists OpenTK installed via package management and not the one installed by MonoGame.

It is said that MonoDevelop ignores GAC and only cares about pkg-config. Why might it be that monogame-sdk did not install required pkg-config files then?

Comment: It might help if you include version information here. Current/ future readers will not understand what versions you are talking about when you say: 1) "I've downloaded latest Monogame" 2) "Note that installation failed due to old MonoDevelop in Debian".  In other words, which versions of the following are you running: Monogame, MonoDevelop, Debian?

Comment: Also, why are you not running the latest version of MonoDevelop?

Comment: @chuex that's an interesting question, I'll try upgrading MonoDevelop.